# Law of Large number

Tags: probability-theory

> Ques. Consider an experiment with probability $p$ of success, probability $1 - p$ of
>   failure. Suppose it is repeated independently, infinitely often. Use the law of large number to show that, not only will the experiment eventually produce a success,
>   but with probability one, it will produce infinitely many of them.

I can show that experiment eventually produce a success. But I have a problem in second part.

**Strong Law of Large number**

Let $X_1, X_2, ...$ be a sequence of
independent, mean zero random variables, such that for each $i$, $E\{X_i^4\} < M$,
where $M > 0$ is a constant. Then $$\lim_{n\to \infty}\frac{S_n}{n}=0 \quad a.e.$$

Comment: Law of large number-s...

Comment: @JeanMarie, Yeah, but I think we will be using strong law as in weak law we have convergence in probability measure.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that the fact "infinitely many successes" can be described by the $\liminf$

So if you describe your experiment by

$$X_k = \begin{cases}
        1 & \mbox{ if succeeded}  \\
        0 & \mbox{ otherwise}
         \end{cases}$$

Then $E[X_k] = p$

And: $S_n = \sum_{k=1}^n X_k$

So if you show $\liminf\limits_{n\to\infty} S_n = +\infty$ you're done.

But now the law of large number tells you $$\frac{S_n}{n} \to p \quad a.s.$$

But what does that mean for $\lim\limits_{n\to\infty} S_n$ and especially for $\liminf\limits_{n\to\infty} S_n$?

Comment: Why infinitely many successes can be described by the $\liminf$ ?

Comment: "Infinitely many successes" is quite adequately described by the usual limit.